# handling failure after maximum number of retries in google app engine task queues

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, task-queue

I am using google-api-python-client and I am using google app engine task queues for some async operations.

For the specific task queue, I am also setting max number of times that the task should be retried(In my case retries are less likely to be successful, so I want to limit them).

Is there a way to write a handler which can handle the case where the task is still failing even after the specified number of retries?

Basically if my retry limit is 5, after 5 unsuccessful retries, I want to move the task to a different queue where it can be retried more number of times with a larger interval between the retries, that way it is more likely to succeed.

From [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/creating-handlers) I believe that I can use **X-AppEngine-TaskExecutionCount** header in each retry and write some custom logic to know when the task is going to execute for the last time and achieve this but I am trying find out if there is any cleaner way.

By the way **X-AppEngine-TaskExecutionCount** specifies(from the doc), ***The number of times this task has previously failed during the execution phase. This number does not include failures due to a lack of available instance.***

Answer (score 1):

At least presently there is no support for automatically moving a task from one queue to another.

One option is to keep the task on the same queue, increase the max number of retries and use the [`retry_parameters`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/queueref#retry_parameters) to customize the retry backoff policy (i.e. the increase of time between retries):

> **retry_parameters**
>
> Optional. Configures retry attempts for failed tasks. This addition
>   allows you to specify the maximum number of times to retry failed
>   tasks in a specific queue. You can also set a time limit for retry
>   attempts and control the interval between attempts.
>
> The retry parameters can contain the following subelements:
>
> - **task_retry_limit**
>
>   The maximum number of retry attempts for a failed task. If specified with **task_age_limit**, App Engine retries the task until
>     both limits are reached. If **0** is specified, the task will not be
>     retried.
> - **task_age_limit (push queues)**
>
>   The time limit for retrying a failed task, measured from when the task was first run. The value is a number followed by a unit of time,
>     where the unit is **s** for seconds, **m** for minutes, **h** for
>     hours, or **d** for days. For example, the value **5d** specifies a
>     limit of five days after the task's first execution attempt. If
>     specified with **task_retry_limit**, App Engine retries the task until
>     both limits are reached.
> - **min_backoff_seconds (push queues)**
>
>   The minimum number of seconds to wait before retrying a task after it fails.
> - **max_backoff_seconds (push queues)**
>
>   The maximum number of seconds to wait before retrying a task after it fails.
> - **max_doublings (push queues)**
>
>   The maximum number of times that the interval between failed task retries will be doubled before the increase becomes constant. The
>     constant is: `2**max_doublings * min_backoff_seconds**`.

But the pattern of the increase will be gradual - doubling after each failure, you can't get a significant "step"-like increase of the time between retries. Still, it may be a good enough solution for which no additional coding is required. Personally I'd go for this approach.

Another approach is to add that logic to determine if that execution is the final retry of the original task and, if so, enqueue a **new** corresponding task on a different queue which has the desired "slower" retry policy. I'm unsure if this is what you were referring to in the question and wanted to avoid.

Comment: 1) Yes, I was trying to avoid using retry count logic in code.
2) I would like to move it to a different queue because it separates the failed tasks from regular tasks and gives a better command over them.